# Unity scoring in Y position

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

So im trying to implement a score where the more i go up(in the y position) more score i have, but my problem is if i fall my score decreases to, i don want that, i want my score to be the max i ever been.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class score : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player;
    public Text scoreText;

    private void Update()
    {
        scoreText.text= player.position.y.ToString("0") ;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public Transform player;
public Text scoreText;
float highest; // Store the value of the highest y-coordinate you've reached

private void Start() => highest = player.position.y;

private void Update()
{
    if (player.position.y > highest) // See (*)
    {
        highest = player.position.y;
        scoreText.text = highest.ToString("0");
    }
}
```

(*) If you go up higher than before, the code in the if-statement executes. If you go down, the value of `highest` doesn't change, so the code in the if-statement does not execute, and your score won't decrease.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare a variable for score and then you just increase it if position y is greater then score.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class score : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player;
    public Text scoreText;
    public int score = 0;


    private void Update()
    {
        if(player.position.y > score)
        {
           score = player.position.y;
           scoreText.text= player.position.y.ToString("0");
        }

    }

  }
```